# Задача "Железная дорога".

Tags: pascal

Алгоритм:

1. Представим шахматную доску(двумерный массив);
2. Возьмем на доске определенные точки: 1. 1 1, 2 6, 3 6, 4 2.
3. Последовательно проводим между этими координатами линии (их получится 4).
4. Элемент списка

А теперь сам вопрос.

```
const
n=10000;
m=10000;
var X:array [1..N, 1..M] of integer;
```

Вот мы задали двумерный массив и спокойно можем взять сколько угодно точек. Но как их соединить? Вопрос всей этой задачи - кол-во путей(линий между этими точками).
В том примере их было 4. По возможности, напишите код (с пояснениями,а то просто спишу).

Comment: По моему это называется ***граф***ы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кода не приведу, поскольку от паскаля далёк.

Но общий смысл такой - если ваш двумерный массив описывает точки на какой-либо поверхности, и координаты точек могут быть только целочисленными, то общее количество точек на этой поверхности будет равно: `E = M x N`

Поскольку в пути участвуют только две точки, то нам нужно взять число **сочетаний** ([биномиальный коэффициент](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)) `по 2 из E`

[Вот тут](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=174170) есть какой-то код

Comment: Для вашей задачи получилось число с 15 нолями

Answer (score 0):

Количество путей равно количеству взятых точек, так как по условию считаем линии и точка не может участвовать более чем в двух линиях. Иначе описание не верно. По пункту 4: линии нужно организовать в список и выдать количество элементов?